# Understanding Form State Management with react-hook-form and zod in shadcn/ui

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using shadcn/ui.In shadcn.ui form they used **react-hook-form** for managing forms and zod for form validation.

## My Question

In React Hook Form, the state of an input field is managed using the **{...register('fieldName')}** function. This function takes the input's 'name' attribute as an argument and sets up event listeners to track changes and update the form state accordingly

for ex

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

function MyForm() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register('fieldName')} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

However, in Shadcn/ui form components, they also utilize the React Hook Form, but I do not have a clear understanding of how it tracks the state.ex

[image]

**even i easily get the value of the input field in onSubmit function easily but if someone explain it then it is easer and get the clear idea that is going on the code**

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Shadcn's form components are just an abstraction of react-hook-form.

If you want to access the state, for example, you can use

```
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            prompt: "",
        },
     })

const { watch } = form
const watchPrompt = watch("prompt")
```

Such that watchPrompt can be accessed, e.g., by

```
useEffect(() => {
   //logic here
   console.log(watchPrompt)
}, [watchPrompt])
```

Not sure if this clarifies things. Probably you're best off reading the react-hook-form documentation.